# Automatic date-based deletion of old mails in mutt from a cron / shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, cron, email, mutt

I would like to automatically delete all mails older 22 days using mutt
So i have created a shell script - which works when started manually:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define mail environment variable to make the mutt script work in cron
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root

# the actual mutt scripting
/usr/bin/mutt -f /var/spool/mail/ACCOUNTNAME -e "push D~d>22d<enter>qy<enter>"
```

It seems like the script does exactly what i am asking for - as long as it is executed manually.

q = quit
y = confirm deletion

Now the big BUT: When executed using cron for example like that

```
55 4 * * * /bin/bash /root/cleanup_mails.sh
```

It seems like the mails are marked for deletion but the deletion itself is not realized.
Any idea why?

Comment: I'm troubleshooting a cron problem right now and used this to diagnose it. Change `55 4 * * * /bin/bash /root/cleanup_mails.sh` to `* * * * * /bin/bash /root/cleanup_mails.sh >> ~/cron.log` to run it once a minute and write the output to a file you can review for clues.

Comment: @TomBrossman good idea in general - but results in an empty log file so far in this particular case.

Comment: Other things to try: Do you need a space before & after the quoted `<enter>` string? Do the angle brackets need to be escaped (`\<enter\>`). Which user's cron is this executed by and are all the necessary $PATH variables set? Cron is tricky to troubleshoot but good luck and I hope that helps.

Comment: `expect` is the tool to use for interacting with a program that normally expects user input. `sudo apt install expect;man expect`.

Comment: You can use screen to get a virtual terminal as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560594/218159)